# jQuery/HTML Calculator not catching Capslock (German Keyboard)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Not so ninja edit:** *I'm working on a German keyboard. When a german keyboard has caps on it treats the number keys as if the shift button was pressed. IIRC this does not happen to UK/US keyboards.*

Just making a simple browser calculator using jQuery/html and have everything hunky dory except for when Caps is on and my calculator starts accepting garbage as input. The below is my input validator. Event.keycode is of no use unfortunately.

```
function validInput(event) {
    return event.keyCode === 13 || event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 10 //enter, backspace and return
        || event.keyCode === 67 // "C" for clear
        || (event.which >= 48 && event.which <= 57) // 0-9 **chars** over the alpha buttons
        || (event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 123); //numpad and fn buttons
```

Thanks for taking the time to read this. Full code below though I don't think you need it...

```
$(function(){
    $("input.number").on("click",clickButton);
    $("body").on("click", revertFocus);              // frag Marc
    $(document).on("keyup keydown", keyHandler)
});

function keyHandler(event) { // handles enter; clear and return keys

    if (event.shiftKey || !validInput(event))
        return false;

    if(event.type == "keyup"){
        if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.keyCode == 10) {
            rechner();
        }

        if (event.keyCode == 67) { //clears the screen
            $("#userInput").val("");
        }
    }else{
        if (event.keyCode == 67) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function rechner() {
    var userInput = $("#userInput").val();
    var answer = eval(userInput.replace(",","."));
    $("#userInput").val(String(answer).replace(".",","));
}

function clickButton(){
    var input = $(this).val();
    if (input=='c'){
        $("#userInput").val("");
        return;
    }
    $("#userInput").val($("#userInput").val() + input);
}


function validInput(event) {
    return event.keyCode === 13 || event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 10 //enter, backspace and return
        || event.keyCode === 67 // "C" for clear
        || (event.which >= 48 && event.which <= 57) // 0-9 over the alpha buttons
        || (event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 123); //numpad and fn buttons
}


function revertFocus() {
    $("#userInput").focus();
}
```

Comment: capslock keycode is 20

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using sometimes `event.wich` and sometimes `event.keyCode` ?

Comment: @Johnny5 - event keyCode detects a certain key being pressed whereas event.which detects which char was printed to screen. Therefor, keyCode doesn't pay attention to capslock and it's effects.

Comment: @Nouphal.M that only helps if they press capslock after logging on to the page, but thanks for the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add another level of validation after text has been entered into the input.
If the text contains invalid chars, remove them.

In any case,
I tested your code in jsfiddle and I could not get any invalid chars into it, with caps or without.  How do you reproduce the issue?

http://jsfiddle.net/jd2Js/

```
$(function(){
$("input.number").on("click",clickButton);
$("body").on("click", revertFocus);              // frag Marc
$(document).on("keyup keydown", keyHandler)
```

});

```
function keyHandler(event) { // handles enter; clear and return keys

if (event.shiftKey || !validInput(event))4
    return false;

if(event.type == "keyup"){
    if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.keyCode == 10) {
        rechner();
    }

    if (event.keyCode == 67) { //clears the screen
        $("#userInput").val("");
    }
}else{
    if (event.keyCode == 67) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

}

```
function rechner() {
 var userInput = $("#userInput").val();
var answer = eval(userInput.replace(",","."));
$("#userInput").val(String(answer).replace(".",","));
```

}

```
function clickButton(){
var input = $(this).val();
if (input=='c'){
    $("#userInput").val("");
    return;
}
$("#userInput").val($("#userInput").val() + input);
```

}

```
  function validInput(event) {
return event.keyCode === 13 || event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 10 //enter, backspace and return
    || event.keyCode === 67 // "C" for clear
    || (event.which >= 48 && event.which <= 57) // 0-9 over the alpha buttons
    || (event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 123); //numpad and fn buttons
```

}

function revertFocus() {
    $("#userInput").focus();
}

Comment: Pants, i forgot to mention I'm on a german keyboard which makes the number buttons act like shift is pressed when capslock is on

Comment: In that case just search the texbox value for @#$% etc... After keypress and remove

Comment: That was my original solution but I don't want the symbols appearing before they get cleared. Not to worry, apart from this glitch it's the only issue (so far) with the calculator so I'm happy enough

Comment: Alright. Though if you were to insist on solving this, you could catch keypress on hidden input, validate the text, then transfer to the visible input.

Comment: D'oh! Thank you!I just now realise that>'s what you were saying all aloing. Correct answer assigned to your good self